# Remove Limit From Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I remove the limit/offset from the below query?

```php
$query = TestModel::where('a', 'b')->limit(100);

$query->removeLimit();
```

I'm using a query from another module and I don't want to change the code.

Comment: Why are you using limit at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the `$limit` property:

```php
$query = TestModel::where('a', 'b')->limit(100);
$query->limit = null;
$unlimited = $query->get();
```

Comment: Doesn't work in laravel 8. Use Abu Sufian's answer instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->getQuery()->limit = null;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `getQuery()` will convert an `Eloquent\Builder` in a `Query\Builder`. Use `$query()->limit(null)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One can reset the limit by passing the `null` value to the `limit` method.

```
$query->limit(null);
```

Works both with `Eloquent\Builder` and `Query\Builder`.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer to your question is - you cannot. Because you have already filtered the result set to a limit of 100 tuples. 
What is the reason for you to avoid the change in code in the Model? Because what @Dhruv has suggested is the correct way to achieve what you want to.
In fact, if you still want to keep the code intact. You can rather define another function in your model this way and use it internally in your old function:

```
public function newFunction(){
    return TestModel::where('a', 'b')->get();
}

public function oldFunction(){
    return $this->newFunction()->limit(100);
}
```

Keeping your code consistent, then use *newFunction()* in your Controller to do whatever you want to.

Answer (score -2):

`get()`: To get all record from table use `get()`:

```
$query = TestModel::where('a', 'b')->get();
```

`limit()`: To limit the number of results returned from the query

```
$query = TestModel::where('a', 'b')->limit(10)->get();
```